# Как сделать отладку Javascript для устройств на Android

Tags: javascript, android, отладка

Есть html страница с Javascript. На десктопных устройствах все работаем корректно. Под android 6 и 7 появляются ошибки. Просто тыкаться и искать ошибку в каждой строчке кода как-то утомительно.  Есть ли возможность отладки с консолью под эти OS?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/

Comment: Используй этот сайт, тут все обьясняют https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/